# Replicating Inline CSS style in CSS style reference

Tags: css

I am trying to modify the CSS of a specific div within my CSS file. The inline style is shown here:

```
div class="widget-area ten columns marT20 left" style="width: 16%; margin: 0px 0px 0px 17px; padding-top: 100px;
```

How can I replicate the inline style above in an external CSS file referencing the specific div element? Here is my attempt:

```
div.widget-area ten columns marT20 left element.style {
      margin:0 0 0 17px;
      padding-top:100px;
      width:16%;
    }
```

The CSS above does not output the desired change in the div element.

Thanks,

AME

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`widget-area`, `ten`, `columns`, etc. are all individual classes. Which means in a CSS stylesheet they must all have a class identifier (`.`)

If you're trying to target any div that contains all 5 classes, then you need to join them. `element.style` is unnecessary. That is what Firebug and other inspectors name the class when there is an inline-style (and therefore no class name)

Try

```
div.widget-area.ten.columns.marT20.left {
  margin:0 0 0 17px;
  padding-top:100px;
  width:16%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inline style declarations override CSS class declarations.

You need to use JavaScript to delete the inline style, allowing it to fall-back to the existing CSS classes, or you need to redefine what is in the inline style attribute.

In either case you need JavaScript.